# Как отдавать 404 страницу? react.js / Koa.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-404

Бек написан с помощью Koa.js.

Принцип такой, что вначале у меня идут роуты для запросов к данным , а затем это:

```
router.get('*', async function(ctx) {
    ctx.type = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
    ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./public/index.html'));
   }
});
```

То есть если ни один роут не совпал, то я отдаю html.

Как тогда мне определить что запрос был к несуществующей странице и отдать 404?

Comment: А какие страницы у вас существуют? По этому роуту мы видем, что несуществующих страниц не бывает.

Comment: Я думаю поставить это в конец файла со всеми путями и также вернуть 404 в хедере

Comment: @AlexeyTen, у меня на реакате допустим нет каких то роутов. И если запрашивать её, то отдается header и footer, потому что они над роутами

Comment: @ishidex2, извините, не смог понять

Comment: @DmitryFilippov ну так опишите роуты на которых вы хотите отдавать index, а по дефолту возвращайте 404